# How to verify lambda has finished execution when triggered via s3?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a use case where putting an object in s3 successfully triggers the lambda. Is there a way to know programmatically that the triggered lambda is done processing ? Right now its processing data and writes to some other s3. Once the process is complete I want to verify the content of other s3. Is there some meta data from `PutObjectResult` , so that, the verification can be done after the lambda finishes the execution ?

### Current Solution

- Lambda normally take from 30s -1 min to finish the execution. Wait until that time and then perform the check.

Comment: Your Lambda could send a notification via SNS or you could use [Lambda Destinations](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/).

Answer (score 1):

You can check this link: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/

Once lambda triggered and executed successfully, you can trigger another SNS/Lamda depending on you scenario.